Custom email routing beyond traditional SMTP server routing
I want to explore ways to optimize our current email-sending process, and I was wondering whether SFMC offers multiple ways to route emails.
I mean to send emails to external systems beyond the traditional SMTP email route (not just sending emails to some SMTP servers).
Does SFMC support integrations with REST APIs, gRPC endpoints, and/or Kafka topics, apart from the traditional SMTP email routing? If yes, what are the options? Are there any custom solutions available? Any experience to share? I tried to search for this myself but I could not find anything.
Thank you.

You can call external APIs via a scripting language and there may be some 3rd party integrations that help with some of that. Ultimately, your question is a XY Problem and in pure technical terms, Marketing Cloud is a poor choice for the type of architecture you're envisioning.
